# How can I filter by domain name within my Rails app in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

It seems like this should be an easy one, but I'm struggling to find the solution. My rails app is hosted on Heroku - actually two heroku deployments, one for staging and one for live. I want to be able to distinguish which one I'm on from within the code. Like:

```
if Rails.root =~ /my_live_domain\.com/ then
       one thing
else
       another
end
```

But it seems Rails.root doesn't contain the domain name. How can I achieve this within Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rails.root` points to your Rails root directory (where your app lies). Here, you need access to your request, e.g:

```
if request.host_with_port =~ /my_live_domain\.com/ then
       one thing
else
       another
end
```